# Does this theorem exist?

Tags: integration

I am not sure if this question has been asked here before, but if it has, I’ll delete this one.

Is there an algorithm or theorem that can be used to verify if the integration of a function is expressible with elementary  functions?

Comment: See [Luoville’s Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)) and [Risch Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm)

Comment: You can also look at some of the Related questions on this page.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral